# Do I need to watch Once Upon a Time in Wonderland to understand Once Upon a Time?

Tags: once-upon-a-time, once-upon-a-time-in-wonderland

As per the wikis there are crossovers between both the series. So do I have to watch Once Upon a Time in Wonderland to understand Once Upon a Time or can it be avoided fully?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think its necessary. Unless I'm mistaken there's only one character, "The Knave Of Hearts", who crossed over to Once Upon A Time and they've never mentioned Alice. Although I'd recommend watching Wonderland, I found it really good.

Comment: I'll throw in that the Knave of Hearts' was introduced and then promptly forgotten about in *Once Upon a Time*, so it is not at all necessary. I second watching *Once Upon a Time in Wonderland*, and would probably recommend it over the main show, if for no other reason than that it had a story with a beginning, middle, and end rather than a status quo reset every season.

Answer (score 3):

No, the main story arcs of OUaT and OUaTiW are completely independent of each other.

But you might want to watch [Frozen](http://www.cinemablend.com/television/11-Reasons-Once-Time-Frozen-Story-Flipping-Weird-67560.html) (not that I have). I can only assume it lends some character development to these new characters, who seem to have been just dropped in on us. I find the back-story that's given to us in the TV show, lacking.

Side note: you *should* watch OUaT before you watch OUaTiW, or just know that *"magic always comes with a price"*, that there's no stronger magic then love, and you're good to go.

Comment: I already watched Frozen. Anyways nice answer +1.